# How can I embed a XML document inside a XHTML document?

Tags: xml, xhtml, embed

For example, how can I embed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <node><![CDATA[Text]]></node>
</root>
```

in my XHTML?

I know I can put it in a CDATA section...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>My title</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>I am a XHTML paragraph!</p>
<div>
    <![CDATA[
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <root>
        <node>Text</node>
    </root>
    ]]>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

... but then I have to remove XML file's CDATA sections and the XML is parsed as text instead of XML.

Then, I get this...

[image]

... but I want something like this:

[image]

Comment: I don't get it - do you want the raw xml displayed, and formatted for readability?

Comment: @Jodes Yes. So I want the browser to parse XHTML using its XHTML parser and parse XML using its XML parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please be aware that CDATA is just a way to escape characters, not a method of embedding. Now on to your question:

As far as I know, the only way to embed an XML file would be using the object tag or an iframe:

```
<!-- Keep in mind that iframe is invalid in XHTML 1.0 and 1.1.-->
<iframe src="data:application/xml,&lt;root&gt;&lt;node&gt;Text&lt;/node&gt;&lt;/root&gt;"/>
<!-- When using `data:mime/type,[data]' the type attribute is overriden -->
<object data="data:application/xml,&lt;root&gt;&lt;node&gt;Text&lt;/node&gt;&lt;/root&gt;"/>
```

The issue here is that some browsers will just display the contents of the XML as inline text, while others will display with an XML viewer window, which is likely what you want.

Here's a chart:

```
   layout engine (browser)    |   <object>    |   <iframe>
 ----------------------------------------------------------
  Gecko (Firefox)             |  inline text  |  XML viewer
  Webkit (Safari / new Opera) |  inline text  |  inline text
  Blink (Chrome/Chromium)     |  inline text  |  inline text
  Presto (old Opera)          |  XML Viewer   |  XML viewer
  Trident (IE5-IE8)           |  inline text  |  XML Viewer
```

Since presto is being replaced, you're left with iframe+firefox as your only workable combination.

If someone can test with IE, please edit-in a your results into the table.

Comment: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qvRzT/1/). Interesting, I thought that `<iframe>` could only render html documents.

Comment: On IE5.5~IE8 the `<iframe>` solution works too. *Edit*: but the object dosn't work

Comment: Using `src="data:application/xml,..."` it works too on Firefox ([**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qvRzT/2/)), but on IE 5.5~8 the wrapper page is redirected to that `data:application/xml` page, and an error is shown.

Comment: Note: it seems `iframe` has no `type` attribute, and then `type="application/xml"` is ignored

Comment: @Oriol you used src instead of data on the second `object`. Works as expected then.