# Is there any option to embedding xhtml in html?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, iframe, xhtml

I have an XML file, which has xsl style sheet with css and html. I wanted to embed this file in existing html.
If any one has idea please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Hey Sanjeev! Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? A quick google search [came up with this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463227/how-can-i-embed-a-xml-document-inside-a-xhtml-document) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712101/embedding-xml-in-html). Any help, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

A very detailed answer to this question can be found in Norm Walsh's W3C task force report

https://www.w3.org/TR/html-xml-tf-report/

But for a one-line summary, section 2.4 asks "2.4 How can islands of XML be embedded in HTML?" and answers "In order to conceal the XML markup from an HTML5 parser's attempts to correct errors, the XML must be stored within a script element."