# How can I embed XML on my HTML webpage from a URL?

Tags: html, xml, iframe, rss

I've been researching and finding it hard to understand how best to embed a URL containing XML on a HTML website. It's for specifically embedding a RSS feed. My idea is to, once it's loaded within the page and automatically grabbing the latest version of the XML file from the URL, style it to display up to three blogposts only from the RSS feed.

I do see it commonly said not to use an `iframe` element, but I'm not finding many other options either. The Javascript I've seen is for loading a complete local XML file. Any suggestions for where to start would be appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

If you're embedding the XML itself, please see [Is there any option to embedding xhtml in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59188628/is-there-any-option-to-embedding-xhtml-in-html)

If you're just embedding a URL referencing the XML, use any of the mechanisms in HTML5, e.g. a custom `<link>` element. The question then is, how are you going to dereference the URL and display the XML? The obvious answer (to me) is with client-side XSLT.

Comment: I actually upvoted, and neglected to respond straightaway as I'm busy researching & implementing a possible solution using jQuery and AJAX. :-) Thank you for your suggestion and input!